# Run contents of string in java

Tags: java, string

Lets say i have this String: `String run = "System.out.println\(\"Hello\"\)"`. What i want to do is run what is in the string to output `Hello` in console.
Maybe there is a method like String.run()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/) , build your app with jar library.

```
import bsh.Interpreter;
private void runString(String code){    
    Interpreter interpreter = new Interpreter();
    try {
         interpreter.set("context", this);//set any variable, you can refer to it directly from string
         interpreter.eval(code);//execute code
    }
    catch (Exception e){//handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in Java 9 you could use the REPL but as it's not there yet You would need to
* create a temporary file with a class with a know to You API
* run javac on it and compile it
* load the compiled class with a class loader
* run the code

If You want to do is running dynamically defined scripts in Your code then You could use Nashorn and JavaScript. It would do what You want. Also You could use Groovy in your project instead of Java - the syntax is similar to Java but Groovy is a dynamic language.

Answer (score -1):

No, you cannot do it and there's no method to run this command in `String`. Anything withing the double quotes becomes `String` literals only and compiler doesn't take care of any command written in that.